# Manifest error: Google Apps script for multiple spreadsheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, shared-libraries, manifest

I want to use 1 google apps script from multiple Google Spreadsheet files within my Google Drive.

I followed this answer: ["you could use Libraries. The idea is that you create one script that you use as a library"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46585776/10595326)

I deployed a library and tried to access it from the Google Apps Script editor. Indeed I can find the library when I enter the library ID (i.e. script ID from script settings), but it gives me a manifest error:

> Die Manifestdatei "appsscript.json" enthält Fehler: Ungültige Dienst-ID: 20012023_sistrix_urlkeyword_standalone

Translated:

> The appsscript.json manifest file contains errors: Invalid service ID: 20012023_sistrix_urlkeyword_standalone

The manifest file looks like this:

```
{
  "timeZone": "Europe/Berlin",
  "dependencies": {},
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
  "runtimeVersion": "V8"
}
```

I was not able to find any hint on how to enter a valid service ID into the manifest file.

Comment: Have you tested the same code in a different Apps Script doc?

Comment: Hi @FernandoLara, thanks for your comment. 
Yes, indeed. 
I tried to publish the library from a existing project. Means: I started from the script editor of the project I wanted to publish. Then I tried to publish a stand-alone-project. Same problem. The stand-alone came with the same manifest:

`{
  "timeZone": "Europe/Berlin",
  "dependencies": {},
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
  "runtimeVersion": "V8"
}`

Comment: Could you provide a minimal reproducible example of the library that you are publishing?

Comment: Hi @FernandoLara, thanks again! I wanted to reproduce the problem with a basic script - in order to have that reproducable example. But I was able to connect it as a library. 

As far as I can tell, the identifier (script-name) may have been the problem. I changed it from "30012023_sistrix_keywordabfrage" to "sisirix abfrage" and taht worked. 

Was it okay if I asked you a new question on this matter?

Comment: Sure thing! If it is related it would be ok, otherwise the community moderators could ask you to create a new post. I just posted your solution from the comments as a community wiki just for future references in case someone else has the same issue later on.

Comment: thanks @FernandoLara! I openec a new question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/75289630/10595326

Answer (score 1):

I'm writing this answer as a community wiki, since the issue was resolved from the comments section, in order to provide a proper response to the question.

According to [s.Panse](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10595326/s-panse), the solution was to change the identifier of the script. It was changed from `30012023_sistrix_keywordabfrage` to `sisirix abfrage` and after that it started to work correctly.